# for(let... in...) does not loop through added keys (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

With the below 2 functions, `addtoObj` logs 'hello' 1 time but `addToArr` logs 'hello' 4 times which I expected to be the case for objects as well. Why is 'hello' only logged once for `addtoObj`?

```js
let addToObj = () => {
  const obj = { 0: true };
  const add = [1, 2, 3];

  for (let key in obj) {
    console.log('hello');
    for (const j of add) {
      if (!obj[j]) {
        obj[j] = true;
      }
    }
  }
};
addToObj()
```

```js
let addToArr = () => {
  const arr = [0];
  const add = [1, 2, 3];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log('hello');
    for (const j of add) {
      if (!arr[j]) {
        arr.push(j);
      }
    }
  }
};
addToArr();
```

Comment: @GalAbra I think the OP's question is moreso, "Why doesn't it continue looping when I've added keys within the loop itself?"

Comment: Because the keys of the object  are only evaluated once, the first time the loop starts. With the other you are using an expression in the loop condition so it is evaluated each iteration

Comment: One of the many, many reasons why you *should never add to/remove from the datastructure you're iterating....*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While a "conventional" `for` loop checks its condition after every iteration, the `for in` loop probably calls `Object.keys(obj)` when it initiates, then it won't re-evaluate this value (even when new keys are added).

From [JS documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> In general, it is best not to add, modify, or remove properties from the object during iteration, other than the property currently being visited. There is no guarantee whether an added property will be visited, whether a modified property (other than the current one) will be visited before or after it is modified, or whether a deleted property will be visited before it is deleted.